# How to display get_post_meta value saved checkbox

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

How to display saved checkbox value or if it is not saved in wordpress;

**example:**

```
<?php
if($field_name_21=="bathrooms") echo 'Yes have bathrooms';
else { echo 'No have bathrooms; }
if($field_name_21=="wc") echo 'Yes have wc';
else { echo 'No have wc; }
?>
```

Comment: Can you be more descriptive about your question?

Comment: Try `echo`ing the value in `$field_name_21` to display the value that's been stored (assuming you're populating the variable somewhere).  That way, you'll know what string to use in your `if` statements.  Also, you're missing a closing quote after "No have bathrooms", which could be your issue

Comment: How exactly could I do?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clear what you're asking.  To check the value of `$field_name_21`, temporarily replace the code in your question with `<?php echo $field_name_21; ?>`  That way you'll know what the value is, and what to use in your `if` statements.  If you mean "how do I set the value of `$field_name_21`?", that's a much bigger question.  I assumed you had already set the value somewhere

Comment: this time it works as: <?php echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'field_name_2', true); ?> and I want to say what saved or which are not saved value...there is no way in wordpress? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Or course it's possible, it's just not clear to me how you've saved your data in WordPress.  Do you have one single field that either contains "wc" or "bathrooms", or a several fields, the first one for "wc", the second one for "bathrooms" and so on?

Comment: Yes.. and I want to say if there is or not there is..

Comment: Sorry - "yes" doesn't help me.  Is there one field?  Or are there several fields?

Comment: This is an field which includes the values bathrooms | wc | bedrooms etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, I'm still not clear on exactly how you have your data stored.  I can see three possibilities; if none of these apply to your situation, please let me know where I've gone wrong.

## Option 1

You have one meta value per property (eg "wc" is stored in with a meta_value of `field_name_1`, "bathrooms" is stored in with a meta_value of `field_name_2`, and so on).

```
<?php
$field_descriptions = array(
    'field_name_1' => 'wc',
    'field_name_2' => 'bathrooms',
    'field_name_3' => 'bedrooms'
);

foreach ($field_descriptions as $field_name => $description) {
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, $field_name, true);

    if ($value) {
        echo 'Yes have ' . $description;
    }
    else {
        echo 'No have ' . $description;
    }
}
?>
```

## Option 2

You have one meta value (eg called `field_name`), and it can have several values store in it, separated by a delimiter (eg `|`).  For example, the stored value could look like `wc|bedrooms`.  This seems unlikely, since your question mentions a saved checkbox, but based on your comment it could be what you're doing.

```
<?php
$possible_values = array('wc', 'bathrooms', 'bedrooms');
$stored_values = explode('|', get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'field_name', true));

foreach ($possible_values as $possible_value) {
    if (in_array($possible_value, $stored_values)) {
        echo 'Yes have ' . $possible_value;
    }
    else {
        echo 'No have ' . $possible_value;
    }
}
?>
```

## Option 3

You have one meta value (eg called `field_name`), and it can have either "wc", or "bathrooms", or "bedrooms".  This seems unlikely, but I include it for completeness.

```
<?php
$possible_values = array('wc', 'bathrooms', 'bedrooms');
$stored_value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'field_name', true);

foreach ($possible_values as $possible_value) {
    if ($stored_value == $possible_value) {
        echo 'Yes have ' . $possible_value;
    }
    else {
        echo 'No have ' . $possible_value;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I would like to thank you for your effort very much!!!
I can say that we are very close, I chose Option 2 which logically make us but beats at **split** `Warning: split(): REG_EMPTY` I give you a picture of his wordpress database, that saved the data: [link](http://oi58.tinypic.com/2q38xlv.jpg)

Comment: Ah - sorry, I meant to use `explode()`, not `split()` (`split` takes a regular expression).  I've updated my answer.  Couldn't see the image for some reason

Comment: Just checked the image again, and I can see it now.  The only thing that might change is you might need a space in your `explode('| '` call.  Or you could look at using a regular expression (if you're comfortable with them) and the [`preg_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function instead of `explode()`.